# MongoDB $lookup on Arrayof Ids with Conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have **parent** collection that has a **property** of an Array of **_ids** to relate it to `Children`.

I'm currently retrieving all children of a parent by doing

```
{
  from: 'Children',
  localField: 'Parent.arrayOfChildrenIds',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'CHILDREN'
}
```

I'd like to filter the returning children to match a condition based on a property of it.

For example, I'd like to only filter out children where their `name` property === 'Bob'.

I've tried using the `pipeline` operator within the `$lookup` but am unable to get results. I believe the complication is because I'm joining on an array of `_ids` as opposed to a 1:1 lookup.

Any ideas? I know I can do this at a later stage in the aggregate but was hoping I could take care of it in the `$lookup` itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookup with pipeline,

- Pass ids in `let`
- match `$and` condition, expression `$expr` condition with `$in` with for `_ids` and second condition for `name`

```
  {
    from: 'Children',
    let: { _ids: '$Parent.arrayOfChildrenIds' },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              $expr: {
                $in: ['$_id', '$$_ids'] }
              }
            },
            { name: 'Bob' }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    as: 'CHILDREN'
  }
```